# How to set Progress Bar to the Linear layout on click of Gallery Items?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am having a GallerView in which I am loading some images from the URL. And on click of the gallery items I am generating a LinearLayout(Dialog type) to display those images.

My scenario is that I want to display that LinearLayout on click of the images in the Gallery and then load the images to get displayed to that layout.

As of now I am displaying that Layout when the images are obtained.So,its taking some time to get the layout displayed.

How can I do that?